# SQL Server: How to get a subitem of sp_helplanguage?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Question: I can get the SQL Server database language by querying:

```
SELECT @@language
```

And I can get further info via

```
EXEC sp_helplanguage
```

How can I query for a column of sp_helplanguage where name= @@language

I do `SELECT * FROM sp_helplanguage WHERE name='DEUTSCH'`

but that obviously doesn't work.

What's the correct way to query it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query the underlying system catalog table directlry:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.syslanguages WHERE name='DEUTSCH'
```